# PHP LARAVEL 5.6, Cómo usar una variable en cualquier controlador

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, variables

estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación y en PHP, tengo un problema con una app que estoy desarrollando. Mi problema es este:
Quiero encontrar todas las facturas que tiene el usuario que inicio sesión, la validación de sí existe o no la tengo, aún así no estoy usando los session_start y demás.
Quiero hacer una consulta en que me liste todas las facturas según el documento que uso para ingresar al sistema.
Pero no sé cómo hacer para crear una variable que me guarde lo que tiene el resultado del input y poder utilizarla en todos los controladores. Espero habermee explicado bien. 
Aquí el código del login:

```
   <form id="login-form" method="post" action="{{URL::TO('login')}}" name="login">
        @csrf

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usuario">Nit*</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Ej: 20003" required="">
          </div>             
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Contraseña*</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" required="" >            
         <br>
          <hr>          
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="boton" type="submit" style="cursor: pointer;">Ingresar</button>



    -----------------LOGIN CONTROLLER----------
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        $nit = $request->input('usuario');
        $clave = $request->input('password');

        $data = DB::select('select cod_rol from tbl_empresas where nit=? and clave=?' , [$nit, $clave]);
        $sec=TblEmpresa::all();
        $col1=DB::select('select cod_rol from tbl_rols where cod_rol = 1');
        $col2=DB::select('select cod_rol from tbl_rols where cod_rol = 2');

        if (count($data)) {
            if ($data == $col1) {
                # code...         

             session_start();

            } else {
                # code...
             session_start();
            return redirect()->action('FacturaEmpresaController@index');
            }

                # code...
        }else {
            echo "<div class='card mt-4'>"."<i class='text-center' style='padding:10px;font-size:15px; color:rgba(252, 27, 27,0.6);'  >"."El usuario no existe, digite los datos correctamente."."</i>"."</div>";
            return view('/login');

        }


    }
```

Comment: no considero correcto que estes metiendo estilos css dentro de los métodos de tu controlador, para eso están las vistas; la idea de usar un Framework MVC como Laravel en este caso es aprender a separar responsabilidades, dentro de lo cual mandas la data a la vista, además que declaras los estilos dentro de la propia etiqueta

Comment: Como bien dice Alfredo Paz no debes incluir html en las clase de laravel, más aún cuando laravel cuenta con un sistema de plantillas blade para facilitar las cosas. Por otro lado, ¿indicas que quieres obtener unos registros en base al usuario logeado, estas utilizando Auth de laravel o es un login implementado por ti mismo? Revisa esto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Comment: Sí, muchísimas gracias, ya lo quité de la vista y le implementé los validation y demás, y ya solucioné mi problema, con la función put de Session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas recién empezando no te recomiendo que te mandes a hacer un login personalizado.
Mi sugerencia para tu problema es de una simple solución.

Según lo que entedí en tu pregunta querés poder acceder en cualquier momento a las facturas del usuario.
**1º**  Si queres cambiarle el nombre a la tabla/Modelo users hacelo y despues actualiza el archivo `config/auth.php`

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

**2º**  Creá un metodo relacionando el usuario con sus facturas.
Suponiendo que la tabla se llama `facturas` y el modelo `Factura`

**User::class**
Relación One To Many

```
/* El usuario puede tener muchas facturas */
public function facturas() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Factura'); // por convención busca el campo user_id en la tabla facturas
}
```

**Factura::class**
Relación One To Many (inversa)

```
/* Una factura solo tiene 1 usuario */
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

**3º**  Una vez relacionados los modelos podes hacer:

- `auth()->user()->facturas` para obtener todas las facturas que tiene el usuario logueado (autenticado)
- `User::with('facturas')` para obtener los usuarios con sus facturas
- `User::find(1)->with('facturas')` para obtener un usuario con sus facturas
- `User::first()->with('facturas')` para obtener el primer usuario con sus facturas
- `Factura::first()->user` para obtener una factura con su usuario